# how to reinstall PDL

Tags: uninstall

I have tried to install perls PDL , and it didnt work so I tried to uninstall it 
I tried to use chmod the permissions and delete the perl/PDL folder 
in windows deledteing folders was very easy in ubuntu I cant figure out how to do it to I had to reinstall every thing , can someone show me how to manually delete a folder 
even tho it has root authority

Thanks

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

actually you can't delete a root folder if  you are not having root authority .

actually to delete a folder and all of its contents even subfolders we have a command like

sudo rm -rf < path of the folder >

Answer (score 0):

To delete a file wit root permissions using the GUI, open a Nautilus (File manager) root session. From the terminal (`Ctrl + Alt + T`) type:

```
gksu nautilus
```

Then find your files and delete them. When you are done. Close Nautilus and the Terminal.